# Overwrite an existing blob in Azure storage does not work with NODE

Tags: node.js, azure, file-upload, stream, busboy

### New question

> When I overwrite a blob and then update the browser is still caching
>   the main image and not the new one. I have read that there is a
>   cache-control property but I can not implement it. I need to clean the
>   blob cache that has just been uploaded

### Old question

I am trying to overwrite an existing blob using connect-busboy middleware and the following method, but the file is not overwritten and I do not understand why.

> createBlockBlobFromStream(container, blob, (Stream), streamLength,
>   options, callback) → {SpeedSummary}
>
> Uploads a block blob from a stream. If the blob already exists on the
>   service, it will be overwritten.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, params) {
    var name;
    req.busboy.on('field', function (fieldname, val) {
      name = val+'.jpg';
    });

 req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      file.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(name);
         console.log(data);
        var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
          bufferStream.end(data);
                var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey);
          blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream('images', name, bufferStream, data.length, function (error, result, response){
              if (!error) {
                  res.send(200,'upload succeeded')
              } else {
                  res.send(500,JSON.stringify(error))
              }
          })
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the behavior you're seeing with the above code? What error are you getting? Please edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Azure Storage SDK for Node API Reference](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createBlockBlobFromStream),

> `createBlockBlobFromStream(container, blob, (Stream), streamLength,
>   options, callback) → {SpeedSummary}`
>
> Uploads a block blob from a stream. **If the blob already exists on the
>   service, it will be overwritten**. To avoid overwriting and instead
>   throw an error if the blob exists, please pass in an accessConditions
>   parameter in the options object.

So you are doing right to overwrite the existing blob file with Azure Storage SDK for Node.

### Edit:

Seems you have encountered upload issue. I would recommend you to try using [createWriteStreamToBlockBlob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L3153) instead of `createBlockBlobFromStream` to upload blob to Azure storage.
The following example works by using *connect-busboy* middleware. create /public folders.
Use the folder structure:

\index.js

\public\index.html

*INDEX.JS*

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var busboy = require('connect-busboy')
var azure = require('azure-storage')

var accountName = "<acountName>"
var accountKey = "<accountKey>"

app.use(busboy())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.post('/upload', function(req, res, params) {
  req.pipe(req.busboy);

  req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename) {
    var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey)
    file.pipe(blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('mycontainer', filename, function(error) {
      if (!error) {
        res.send(200, 'upload succeeded')
      } else {
        res.send(500, JSON.stringify(error))
      }
    }))

  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

*INDEX.HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I used a lot. I use your code and it works just like mine. I suspect that the portal azure admin will have blocked overwriting permissions by some option on the portal. He comes in a few weeks. Anyway your code was used to verify and confirm that the problem is another. thank you very much!

Comment: or may be it is a frontend cache problem im using angular2