# Reading file from request and uploading it to storage

Tags: javascript, backend, azure-blob-storage

I am implementing API that will ahve to handel request - one of them is POST tha will store in it image file (example: jpg) that i will have to upload to azure storage.

I found module, that will alllow putting fiels into storage (seems so, I couldn't try it) if presented as stream or text (so, probably going with stream)

> azure-storage

I then used Postman to send request with file:
(
[Tool for sending multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request) 
)

but now, in request's body there is just big mass of incomprehensible characers (seems ok, since it is image), but I stucked now - I do not know how to get that file from reuqest and pass it to module's function?

Some more code:

```
route.route('/photo')
    .post(
    (req, res) => {
            upload(req);
    })
```

and part for `upload(request)` function (now implemented with fucntion useing local file, so I could test if it even worked with connection given - It did!):

```
process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = 'MyConnectionString'
upload(request) {

        blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(
            ContaienrName,
            FileNameInContainer,
            'D:\\My\\Path\\To\\image.jpg', 
            function (error, result, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log(' >> File uploaded!');
                }
                else {
                    console.log(' >> File NOT uploaded!');
                }
                console.log(' >> --------------------');
                console.log(' >> ERROR : ');
                console.log(error);
                console.log(' >> --------------------');
                console.log(' >> RESULT : ');
                console.log(result);
                console.log(' >> --------------------');
                console.log(' >> RESPONSE : ');
                console.log(response);
                console.log(' >> --------------------');

                resolve(resultReturning);
            }
        );
}
```

EDIT #1:
I managed to get "part" of requst that i will ha ve to handel i nacciuality:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="71127.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to parse incoming `multipart/form-data` to a stream. You can use [connect-busbody](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) to do that. For more infomation, please refer to Mick Cullen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload/23843746#23843746).

Second, use [`createWriteStreamToBlockBlob`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createWriteStreamToBlockBlob__anchor) instead of `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile` to provide a stream to write to a block blob. The sample code for node.js with [azure-storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) you can check out [my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383989/overwrite-an-existing-blob-in-azure-storage-does-not-work-with-node/41390038#41390038).